# In C++, how to access the members of a nested class from a pointer to the drived class

Tags: c++, pointers, inner-classes

Can you please explain me why I receive error trying to access the members of the nested class from the derived class:

```
class Base
{
public:
    static int A;
    class inside_Base {public: static int B;};
};

int Base::A = 1;
int Base::inside_Base::B = 2;

class Derived : public Base {};
```

then in main I have:

```
Base * p;
p = new Derived();
```

when I try to print **p->inside_Base::B** I receive below error:

```
error: 'Base::inside_Base' is not a base of 'Derived'
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can do `Derived::inside_Base::B`, but you can't do that on variable, as you were trying. 
You can't even do `Base b; b::inside_Base::B`. It's not the inheritance matter. It's matter of usage `.`, `->` operators and `::` construction.

Comment: But I can use p->A  p is a pointer and why I can not point to inside_Base clsss but I can point to A. both of them are members of the same Base class.

Comment: class inside_Base{}; is a class definition. You have not actually created any members of said class to point to

Comment: inside_Base class has a static member which should be accessed with only class name and does not need any instantiation to be accessed. My question is why **Base::A** is equal to **p->A** but **Base::inside_Base::B** is not equal to **p->inside_Base::B** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @V.Kravchenko said, you should not use static members through created objects. There is no variables polymorphism, only the functions one.

Usually you do not need to refer to `inside_Base` through `Derived`, because you lie that the `Base::inside_Base` is a nested class of `Derived`. But if you want it very much, you can `typedef` it:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    typedef Base::inside_Base   inside_Base;
};
```

In this case you can write `Derived::inside_Base::B`, for example (checked in MSVC 9.0). But, of course, it has no polymorphism as the class is defined statically in compile time.

### What means `p->A`? Why not `p->inside_Base::B`?

`p->A` is equivalent to `Base::A`. It is C++ feature that allow you to use static variables as non-static. Don't know why it is needed.

`var->Class::member` says that you want a `member` symbol from class `Class` related to `var` instance. It is needed to resolve ambiguous symbols that may be used with `var`. For example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    int x = {1};
};

class Derived
{
public:
    int x = {2};
};

void main()
{
    Derived var
    std::cout << var.x << " " << var.Base::x;
}
```

Out will be `2 1`. In second call we want to get *exactly* `Base`'s member.

So, `p->inside_Base::B` says that you want a `B` from exactly class `inside_Base` related to `p` variable. But `inside_Base` is not a `p`'s class and not a derived one. You can ask: why compiler doesn't scan nested classes? I think that because nobody needs it. It will complicate compilation and will not benefit as it doesn't resolve any ambiguousness.

Comment: I can access B without `typedef` by using `Derived::Base::inside_Base::B` and there is no need for `typedef`.   I just want to know why `Base::A` is equal to `p->A` but `Base::inside_Base::B` is not equal to `p->inside_Base::B` I would like to access `inside_Base::B` through pointer `p`

Comment: @ehsan Because syntax doesn't support this feature. It would lead more complicated syntax analysis without any advantages. Why do you want to use static things through dynamic `p`?